# How do I access an asset from a test?

Tags: android

I can't access an asset even though I've added the `assets` folder underneath `/src/main` and am referencing it using the following code: `getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open("test.jpeg")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `getTargetContext()` instead. To use an asset in a test case, do the following:

- Create the folder `/src/main/assets`
- Add your asset into this folder
- Your test case should `extends InstrumentationTestCase`
- Access your file using the following code `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getAssets().open(yourfile)`